# how to create thread which should run for every 30secs using java?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I want to create a thread in java that should run every 30secs,and should delete the particular record in database in mySQL.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried?  Can you edit your post to show some code samples?  What research have you done?

Comment: And what is your question? If we can write code for you? Show us your solution and we'll help you improve it.

Comment: [SO is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/148287)!

Comment: Why not use the [MySQL event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html)?

Comment: sorry friends I am new to this.accept my appologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did something like this for the same reason, here's my code:

```
package com.xxx.thread;

public class Updater implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            try {
                //do work here
                Thread.sleep(1000*60*60); //sleep time in ms
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }



}
```

To start the thread:

```
 Thread myThread = new Thread(new Updater());
 myThread.start();
```

Comment: Thanks u so much above code was useful to me

Answer (score 2):

Need some code samples?

```
public void schedule(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO write your code
        }
    }, 1000,1000*30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the accepted answer. `Thread.sleep` is probably the worst way to solve your problem, since it's inaccurate and messy (requires loop + call to `sleep` + cancellation mechanism). The most acceptable way is to use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html):

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
exec.submit(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          // update db here
      }
   }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```